# Why Jetty 9 doesn't respect finalName?

Tags: maven, plugins, jetty

I am using Maven with Jetty Plugin, but my projects lost their finalName in the URL.
They used to be like localhost:8080/projectname and now they are only localhost:8080.
Is there a way to force Jetty to use the finalName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven's `<project>/<build>/<finalName>` and your Jetty `contextPath` are completely unrelated when it comes to the jetty-maven-plugin.

The `contextPath` for jetty-maven-plugin defaults to `/`.

You'll want to [configure your webapp](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp) per the instructions for the jetty-maven-plugin, with a focus on the `<contextPath>` element in your plugin `<configuration>`.

Comment: Many thanks Joakim, more precisely what I had to do:
<plugin><configuration><webApp><contextPath>...